# How to install apt-get and dpkg

Tags: centos, apt, dpkg

I try to install `apt-get` on CentOS 7 (Core), but I received

```
bash: dpkg: command not found
```

when I tried to extract Debian files. How can I install both of them?

Comment: Are the packages that you want to use (_not_ `apt`, but the ones you ultimately want to install) not available through `yum`?

Comment: `dpkg` is available in the `epel` repository. Echoing @Kusalananda, please use `apt` and `dpkg` to extract/examine .deb files, not to install them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't install `apt` in CentOS. Neither you install any `.deb` packages there.

In CentOS you use `yum` (CentOS 7 and below), or `dnf` (CentOS 8). These will allow you to install RPM packages.

Ubuntu vs CentOS have different package manager (dpkg vs RPM). That's how they are *different distros* in the first place.. :)

If you've jumped from Ubuntu to CentOS recently and struggling with some learning curve, you may want to try this `apt` alias for CentOS [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/apt-centos). It's not real `apt`, of course. But will allow you to run the commands you're used to and get similar results in CentOS.

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks a lot. I installed dnf, and then ran/installed ImageMagick rpms using dnf command. That resolved my problem. Initially I was trying with yum but it was not working properly with certain libs missing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg` is a tool to manage `.deb` packages for Debian based systems, `apt-get` is the tool to do installation and dependency solving for Debian based systems.

The CentOS 7 equivalents would be `rpm` for handling `.rpm` packages and `yum` for installation and dependency solving.  For CentOS 8, the installation is done with `dnf`.

You can get started with `yum` by initiating a simple search:

```
yum search project_name
```

Then try to install one of the resulting packages with:

```
yum install package_name
```

You can install `dpkg` on CentOS easily enough with `yum install dpkg`.  With enough effort, you can get `apt-get` installed, but it is ultimately pointless as there are no available `.deb` repositories that would deliver packages that work or could be installed in a CentOS system.

If you need to be able to build `.deb` packages on your CentOS system, it is easy enough to create a Debian `chroot` to do `.deb` package builds.

If you only want to ever use `apt-get` and `dpkg`, then you should not be using CentOS and pick up a Debian based distribution.

Comment: It should be noted that having two package managers is worse than "pointless" it's liable to screw up your system.  Anything you try to install with `apt` will most likely draw in dependencies such as libc which are already installed via `yum`.  But `apt` will not understand they are already installed. The conflict could be very bad for your system.